# Проблема с require_once при подключении phpspreadsheet в Joomla!, PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, joomla3, phpspreadsheet

Пишу скрипт в своем простом модуле Joomla, который с помощью jQuery находит необходимый мне элемент по его классу, отправляет ajax запрос файлу php с содержимым тега, выполняет необходимую обработку и отправляет мне html разметку в определенный тег.
файл index.php:

```
 <script>
    
    jQuery(function($) {
    let nameAccord = $('.panel-title').html();
    if(nameAccord == "test2"){
        $.ajax({
        data: {action: 'test2'},
        type: 'post',
        url: '/getTable.php',
    success: function(data) {
        $('.panel-body').html(data);
        }
    });
    }
    if(nameAccord == "test1"){
        $.ajax({
        data: {action: 'test1'},
        type: 'post',
        url: '/getTable.php',
    success: function(data) {
        $('.panel-body').html(data);
        }
    });
    }
    
    });
    
</script>
```

Файл getTable.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    
} 
if($action == "test2"){
    echo '<div class = "createClass">Полученное содержимое 2</div>';
}
if($action == "test1"){
    echo '<div class = "createClass">Полученное содержимое 1</div>';
}
?>
```

Вот так если смотреть я получаю то, что мне нужно в теории. На практике же я использую библиотеку phpspreadsheet для Joomla!, которая позволяет читать Excel с помощью PHP.
Я научился в помощью нее читать и выводить Excel-содержимое. Но цель моя заключается в том, чтобы делать разную обработку, разных файлов в зависимости от содержимого класса panel-title.
Что я делаю, я в файл getTable.php подключаю phpspreadsheet, использую классы из этой библиотеки:

```
require_once JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/libraries/phpspreadsheet/phpspreadsheet.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
```

В соответствующее условие я заношу обработку:

```
if($action == "test2"){
    
    $file = 'test.xlsx'; 
    $excel = IOFactory::load($file); 
    $excel->setActiveSheetIndex(18); 
    
    $sheet = $excel->getActiveSheet();
    $html = '
    <div class = "start__price__table">
    <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead class = "unique-color-dark">
    <tr class="text-white">
      <th>Колонка1</th>
      <th>Колонка2</th>
      <th>Колонка3</th>
      
    </tr>
    </thead>';
    foreach ($sheet->getRowIterator(2) as $row) {
        $html .= '<tr class = "row-st">';
        $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
        foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
            $value = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
            if(!empty($value)){
                if (Date::isDateTime($cell)) {
                    $value = date('d.m.Y', Date::excelToTimestamp($cell->getValue()));
                }
        
                $html .= '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
            }
            // если дата, то преобразовать в формат PHP
            
        }
        $html .= '<tr>';
    } 
    $html .= '</table></div>';
    echo $html;
}
```

По итогу я разметку в переменной $html, но я ничего не получаю.
Я решил проверить подключение require_once и добавить в первый пример файла getTable.php:
Снова файл getTable.php

```
<?php
require_once JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/libraries/phpspreadsheet/phpspreadsheet.php';
if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    
} 
if($action == "test2"){
    echo '<div class = "createClass">Полученное содержимое 2</div>';
}
if($action == "test1"){
    echo '<div class = "createClass">Полученное содержимое 1</div>';
}
?>
```

Теперь у меня даже рабочий пример не работает. Я понял, что все дело в require_once я выводил ошибки с помощью:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
```

Была одна ошибка и я ее устранил.
Как мне устранить данную проблему или хотя бы помогите разобраться в тех местах, где я неправ. Спасибо заранее!
PS: ссылка на библиотеку для joomla! : https://github.com/ivanramosnet/PhpSpreadsheet-Joomla-Library?ysclid=lb39sgwv28663316531

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем проблема заключалась в файле библиотеки autoload.php, в строке defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die;. В общем, файл getTable.php не мог провериться Jooml'ой, что открывается из среды Joomla. Для решения проблемы я перед require_once в getTable.php вставил следующее:

```
if (!defined('_JEXEC')) {
    define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
    define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );
}
```

Таким образом, я проверил наличие файла в корне Joomla! и не нарушил безопасности, можно было также просто убрать или закомментировать строку JEXEC...